# How to stop my process if I find the list in sorted in any intermediate point-IN BUBBLE SORT?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

```
#inlcude<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int arr[30],num,i,j,k,temp,l=0;
 printf("Enter the number of elements :\n");
 scanf("%d",&num);
 for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
 {
   printf("Enter element %d\n",i);
   scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
 }
for(k=1;k<=num;k++)
{if(arr[k]>arr[k+1])
  l++;}
 if(l!=0)
 {   
 for(i=2;i<=num;i++)
 {l=0;
   for(k=1;k<=num;k++)
   {
     if(arr[k]>arrk+1])
     l++;}
   if(l!=0)
   {for(j=1;j<num;j++)
    {
     if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
     {
       temp=arr[j];
       arr[j]=arr[j+1];
       arr[j+1]=temp;
     }
    }
  printf("\nAfter pass %d elements are:",i-1);
  for(k=1;k<=num;k++)
     printf("%d",arr[k]);}
  else
     break;
     }
  }
  printf("\nsorted list is:\n");
  for(k=1;k<=num;k++)
     printf("%d ",arr[k]);
   retrun 0;
 }
```

This is the Bubble sort program. My query is I need to stop my process if I find my list is sorted in any intermediate point. I even did that... But still there is some problem with this program. It's not getting accepted in portal, It triggers as the program is "Wrong Answer". I guess there may be mistakes in finding out the intermediate point. Help me out to figure out this..

Comment: Why are you using 1-based indices? Array indices in C generally start at 0, not at 1. Also your'll get an overflow if somebody enters an n > 29.

Comment: Eugenics huh? Have you got verified upon submission?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag and check if the list is sorted like this:

```
for(i=0; i ......
{
flag=1; // We are setting a "break point" here by setting flag=1; If any exchange of elements take place inside if loop, flag will be
//set back to zero inside the if block statements.
for(j=0; j ......
{
if (a[j]>a[j+1])
{
temp=a[j];
a[j]=a[j+1];
a[j+1]=temp;
flag=0; // flag is set back to zero because there occured an "exchange of element"
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
  int array[100],i,n,c,swap,flag=0;
  printf("Enter the number of elements :\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(c=0;c<n;c++)
  {
  printf("Enter element %d\n",c+1);
  scanf("%d",&array[c]);
  }
  printf("Unsorted list is :\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d ",array[i]);
  printf("\n");
  for(c=0;c<n-1;c++)
  {
    if(flag==0)
    {
      flag=1;
     for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
     { 
        if(array[i]>array[i+1])
        {
          swap=array[i];
          array[i]=array[i+1];
          array[i+1]=swap;
          flag=0;
        }
    }
    printf("After Pass %d elements are :",c+1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      printf("%d ",array[i]);
    }                   
    printf("\n");
    }
  }
  printf("Sorted list is :\n");
  for(c=0;c<n;c++)
    printf("%d ",array[c]);
  return 0;
}
```