# Modified bubble sort passes error

Tags: c

Write a C program to perform bubble sort on an array of n elements.

Note: stop the process if u find that the list is sorted in any intermediate point

It worked correctly for other numbers but when i am giving input 3,2,4,5,6 it does not show the passes correctly.Instead of showing the passes correctly it repeat the same value for every pass.

Enter the number of elements :

5

Enter the element 1

3

Enter the element 2

2

Enter the element 3

4

Enter the element 4

5

Enter the element 5

6

Unsorted list is :

3 2 4 5 6

After Pass 1 elements are :2 3 4 5 6

After Pass 2 elements are :2 3 4 5 6

After Pass 3 elements are :2 3 4 5 6

After Pass 4 elements are :2 3 4 5 6

Sorted list is :

2 3 4 5 6

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

int s,i,j,temp,a[20],count=0,x,n=0;
printf("Enter the number of elements :\n");
scanf("%d",&s);
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
{
    printf("Enter element %d\n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
printf("Unsorted list is :\n");
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
{
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<(s-1);i++)
{
    n++;
    for(j=0;j<(s-i)-1;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]>a[j+1])
        {
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=temp;
            count++;
         }
    }
    if(count<0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nAfter Pass %d elements are :",n);
        for(x=0;x<s;x++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[x]);
        }
     }
   }
   printf("\nSorted list is :\n");
   for(i=0;i<s;i++)
       printf("%d ",a[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the first pass sorts it, then it continues as if it's not noticing.  Have you written a is_sorted() to check on this?

Comment: But at last we can the sorted list available because if the program would have run correctly then it must have show 2 passes,but it's not showing it.

Comment: Two problems: (1) check if count <= 0, (2) initialize count to zero above the line reading "n++";

Comment: actually `count == 0`, it can't be less. (well, it shouldn't)

Comment: `for(j=0;` change to `for(j=count=0;` and `if(count<0)` change to `if(count==0)`

Comment: I altered the code but problem persisted because when i am inputting values 34,23,54,45,66 then it shows only one pass but it should have shown 2 passes.

Comment: You should be able to find this sort of thing with your debugger: decide what you think your programme is going to do, then watch closely to make sure what you expect to happen does happen when you expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset count to 0 at the beginning of your loop.  When you swap elements, it increments, but you'll never trip `if (count <= 0)` unless you are counting only the swaps on this pass.

Comment: According to your logic i altered the code but for the values like 1,2,3,4,5 at least it should have one pass but it directly gives the sorted data,help me out ,what change i should??????

Comment: Its exiting before it fronts "first run."  Try moving the if count <= 0 to the last thing in the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
  int array[100],i,n,c,swap,flag=0;
  printf("Enter the number of elements :\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(c=0;c<n;c++)
  {
  printf("Enter element %d\n",c+1);
  scanf("%d",&array[c]);
  }
  printf("Unsorted list is :\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d ",array[i]);
  printf("\n");
  for(c=0;c<n-1;c++)
  {
    if(flag==0)
    {
      flag=1;
     for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
     { 
        if(array[i]>array[i+1])
        {
          swap=array[i];
          array[i]=array[i+1];
          array[i+1]=swap;
          flag=0;
        }
    }
    printf("After Pass %d elements are :",c+1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      printf("%d ",array[i]);
    }                   
    printf("\n");
    }
  }
  printf("Sorted list is :\n");
  for(c=0;c<n;c++)
    printf("%d ",array[c]);
  return 0;
}
```

-I was also stuck at the process. Above solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714962/how-to-stop-my-process-if-i-find-the-list-in-sorted-in-any-intermediate-point-in/) by @subin sv from this link. Credit goes to him. By using flag for checking whether it is sorted or not is the main logic.